# Elasticsearch Scripting: updating array value

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my document

```
{
    "name": "andrew",
    "b": [{"x":"c1", "y": 0}, {"x":"c2", "y": 0}]
}
```

I want to find element in the array field "b" and update the entire object. I tried this script but it does not update. Any ideas?

```
{
    "script": "for (item in ctx._source.b) { if (item['x'] == x_id) { item = newobj; } };",
    "params": {
        "x_id": "c1",
        "newobj" : {"x":"c1", "y": 4222}
    },
    "lang":"groovy"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
{
  "script": "for (int i=0;i<ctx._source.b.size();i++) { item=ctx._source.b[i]; if (item['x'] == x_id) { ctx._source.b[i] = newobj} };",
  "params": {
    "x_id": "c1",
    "newobj": {
      "x": "c1",
      "y": 4222
    }
  },
  "lang": "groovy"
}
```

Comment: what to use update API or update query API while executing ?

Comment: I hope update API works, If you want to update many docs using query you have to use update query API