# how to index questions and answers in elaticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-6

I am doing a project to index questions and answers of a website in elasticsearch (version 6) for search purpose.

I have first thought of creating two indexes as shown below, one for questions and one for answers.

questions mapping:

```
{"mappings": {
"question": {
  "properties": {
    "title":{
        "type":"text"
    },
    "question": {
      "type":  "text"
    },
    "questionId":{
        "type":"keyword"
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

answers mapping:

```
{"mappings": {
    "answer": {
      "properties": {
        "answer":{
            "type":"text"
        },
        "answerId": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        },
        "questionId":{
            "type":"keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have used multimatch query along with term and top_hits aggregation to search the indexed Q&As ([referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509045/filter-elasticsearch-results-to-contain-only-unique-documents-based-on-one-field)).I used this method to remove the duplicates from the search results. As answers or the question itself of the same question can appear in the result. I only want one entry per question in the results. the problem I am facing is to paginate the results. there is no possible way to paginate aggregation in elasticsearch. It can only paginate hits not aggregations.

then I thought of saving the both question and answers in one document, answers in a Json array. the problem with this approach is that there is no clean way to add, remove, update a specific answer in a given question document. only way I found was using a groovy script ([referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712228/elasticsearch-scripting-updating-array-value)). which is deprecated in elasticsearch v6 AFAIK.

Is there a better and clean way to design this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the duplicate search results are coming, it will be helpful if you could share your query on ES.

Comment: the duplicate results occur when when multiple answers or the question itself is matched for a query, which finally points the the same question.

Comment: If you will be using the parent-child relation it will solve your duplication problem also, as you will be querying or aggregating using has_child or has_parent

Answer (score 6):

**Parent-Child Relationship**

Use the parent-child relationship. It is similar to the nested model, and allows association of one entity with another. You can associate one document type with another, in a one-to-many relationship.
More information on here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Child documents can be added, changed, or deleted without affecting the parent nor other children. You can do pagination on the parent documents using the **Scroll API**.
Child documents can be retrieved using the **has_parent** join.

The trade-off: you do not have to take care of duplicates and pagination problems, but parent-child queries can be 5 to 10 times slower than the equivalent nested query.

Your mapping can be like the following:

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "question": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "question": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "questionId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "answer": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "question"
      },
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "answerId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "questionId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```